# Differentiate timeout from STDIN in select()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm writing a program that will receive messages, receive user input(STDIN) and also send out periodic messages to other servers. So I used **select()** in my program. Below is the pseudocode:

```
// master is the fd set
FD_SET(0, &master); // add STDIN into master set
FD_SET(listener, &master); // listener is the listening UDP socket
int indicator = select(...args...);

// have data coming in
if(indicator > 0 ){
    // do something
}
// user input some data
else if(indicator == 0){
    // do something if user input data
}
//Here is the question. How can I differentiate STDIN from timeout?
else if(){
    // do something if timeout occurred
}
```

I want to know is there a way to differentiate timeout from STDIN, since both will make select() return 0 in this case?

Comment: A return of zero indicates timeout, and not that file descriptor zero is ready.  (You have perhaps misread the description of select()'s return value.  It returns the number of file descriptors that are read/write/exception ready.  It does not return the number of a file descriptor which is read/write/ready.)

Comment: The FD_ISSET() macro may be of interest here as well.

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, you are right! So in this case, if **select()** return 0, then it is a timeout event. If user input is detected, the actual fd is 0. But the return value is not zero. It should be 1. Am I right?

Comment: The return value will be 1 if STDIN or `listener` — but not both — is ready.  As @JeremyFriesner said, use FD_ISSET to see which one specifically is ready.  The return value will be 2 if both are ready.